# What is veteran status, and how do you get it?

Tags: battlefield-3

I noticed that in my battlelog (listed below my platoons) I have a veteran status for BF3 and BattleField Play 4 Free.

1. What BF games qualify for veteran status?
2. How do I set up these games so the veteran status is shown on my battlelog?
3. What does being a veteran do for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Battlefield Wikia](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Battlefield_Veteran):

> Battlefield 3 is now the fourth game in the series to use the Battlefield Veteran system. If someone has played an older Battlefield game, they can receive the M1911 pistol in the game just by registering an old Battlefield game to the website www.battlefield3.com/veteran. It also **unlocks two variants of the M1911**, the tact and suppressed versions.

I'm not certain how one logs into the Veteran site to register other games, as the link provided just redirects to the BF3 site.  Some folks apparently have 10 or more Veteran Points, and supposedly it's possible to make your veteran status show on your dog tags.

Comment: Like you said the BF3 link appears to be dead. But you can add games to the veteran list of Battlefield Bad Company 2 and they will be automatically transfered to your BF3 profile. http://www.battlefieldbadcompany2.com/veteran

Answer (score 3):

Your veteran status is based on how many other games in the series you have played. Certain games offer rewards based on your Veteran status, Bad Company 2 for example gave you the M1 Garand for use in the multiplayer.

All Battlefield games onward from Battlefield 2 (expansions as well) count towards your status but I think there are only a few (maybe four like agent said) that actually make use of it (that being displaying your status in game or giving you a reward)

Originally I think you had to register the game to your account on www.battlefield3.com/veteran but now a lot of it is tracked automatically based on whether you have multiplayer stats on the EA servers.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You earn **Veneran status** by adding games (activation code) to your **Battlefield** or **Orgin** online profile. For example I log in on [battlefieldbadcompany2.com/veteran](http://www.battlefieldbadcompany2.com/veteran) and I see something like this...

[image: Veteran status]

If you have Orgin by adding game code [on this site](https://www.origin.com/pl/account) or in app - but I'm not so sure.

List of games that can give you **Veteran** status;

- BF 3
- BF:BC2
- BF 1942
- BF 1943
- BF 2
- BF 2142
- BF: BC
- BF Heroes
- BF Modern Combat
- BF Play4Free
- BF Vietnam

Hope this helps.