# Is the M1911 still a bonus gun after signing up for EA Origin account?

Tags: battlefield-3

I noticed after signing up for my BF3 Origin acct. it was stated i would receive the M1911 .45 cal sidearm.  Where do I find this?  Or is this bonus expired?
Thanks John

Comment: Also see this question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41342/what-is-veteran-status-and-how-do-you-get-it about Veteran status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The M1911 is unlocked through EA's Gun Club. You need to sign up for the Gun Club to unlock it (you will get the M1911, M1911 Suppressed, and M1911 Tact).

Alternatively, you can receive the weapon if you are a 'Battlefield Veteran' - that is, have played a previous Battlefield game on that EA account - Battlefield 2, Bad Company, Bad Company 2, etc.

If you have done these things, you may have to restart the game, restart your console if playing on 360 or PS3, or log in to Battlelog again.

Comment: If you don't have any of the other "pay to play" games.  You can sign up, with the same EA account to the "free to play" games: Battlefield Heroes (http://www.battlefieldheroes.com) and Battlefield Play4Free (http://battlefield.play4free.com)

Comment: Also, Battlefield 1942 is free now. I added it to my library and now I also have access to the aforementioned three weapons. (http://www.battlefield.com/battlefield-1942)

Comment: What do you mean by restart like completely start all over again back to level 1?

Comment: No, turn off the console and back on again and start the game back up.